# Run binary from with root Android Application

Tags: java, android, unix, android-ndk, native

I want to run a binary at `/dev/local` named native(I pushed it through adb), with root permission.
In order to achieve that, I wrote the following code:

```
    try {
        root=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(root.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream osRes = new DataInputStream(root.getInputStream());
        os.writeBytes("/data/local/native\n");
        os.flush();
        TextView output=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
        output.append(osRes.readLine());
        root.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This gave me a `NullPointerException`.So, I tried changing it to:

```
    try{
        root=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        root.waitFor();
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(root.getOutputStream());
        DataInputStream osRes = new DataInputStream(root.getInputStream());
        os.writeBytes("/data/local/native\n");
        os.flush();
        TextView output=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview);
        output.append(osRes.readLine());
        root.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Toast.makeText(this, e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

With this I get BrokenPipe error.

Kindly help me, I want to run a binary with root privileges, is there any alternative way or what is it that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try running `su -c /path/to/executable`.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered this many times and helped others as well. Please try this:

```
Usage: Run(new String[]{"/system/bin/sh", "-c", "su"});

public String Run(String[] cmd) {
    StringBuffer theRun = null;
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        int read;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            theRun = output.append(buffer, 0, read);//output
        }
        reader.close();
        process.waitFor();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
        return theRun.toString();//return output
}
```

Also, this link is helpful: http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-requesting-root-access-in-your-app/

Answer (score -1):

I know my answer is late, but if you are still facing this issue, here is what I did. I also had to run a binary with root permission. I tried several things, like placing the binary in the /system/app folder, where the system apps run from and hence have root permission. But it did not work. So, I had to modify the su.c file and recompile the kernel, as mentioned in [THIS](http://mydragonboard.org/community/hw-sw-8074/root-permissions-with-android-application/) site. If recompiling the kernel is not an option, you can try making the same change in a roottool (like busybox) and recompiling that. You can now use "busybox su -c" instead of just "su -c".

Comment: Other than tangentially raising the fact that a stock Android 'su' is not usable for the desired purpose, this is a bunch of mistaken speculation which should be deleted. Recompiling the kernel has no part in it at all.