# Read private file (/data/data folder) in rooted device

Tags: android, inputstream, root

I need to access a file contained in the private folder of another app. I have granted my app the root privilege and changed the permissions - although I think it's not necessary - but when I try to read from the file, I get "permission denied".

This is the code:

```
File file = new File("/data/data/other.app/shared_prefs/file.xml");
if(file.exists()) {

  try {
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 " + file.getAbsolutePath());
      InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

      ....
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't be a space here **"chmod 777"** before the file name?

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the code but still I can't open the file

Answer (score 1):

Probably you wont be able to do this, because each app on android has a user with unique permissions.

See this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#userid

> Any data stored by an application will be assigned that application's user ID, and not normally accessible to other packages. When creating a new file with getSharedPreferences(String, int), openFileOutput(String, int), or openOrCreateDatabase(String, int, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory), you can use the MODE_WORLD_READABLE and/or MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE flags to allow any other package to read/write the file. When setting these flags, the file is still owned by your application, but its global read and/or write permissions have been set appropriately so any other application can see it.

Comment: Mmh I don't agree. There are "root browsers" who can browse and open files everywhere (also the one that I am trying to open), so this is doable

Comment: This answer is correct with regard to "Android" but inapplicable to hacked builds which have some sort of 'su' root shim.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot break up the su and the chmod operations like that.

This code:
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 " + file.getAbsolutePath());

Does not result in the chmod being executed in a root shell. Each call to exec kicks off a NEW process.

You need to run the commands you need all within a single process. The easiest way to do that is to write a shell script to your /data/data directory that does these operations for you and then run that through the sh shell processor.

Please note that good security practice would be to chmod the file back to not world readable after you are done with it in your app so that you are not leaving the other app exposed forever.

This answer looks to have what you need: [Run binary from with root Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446969/run-binary-from-with-root-android-application/10221574#10221574)

Comment: Thanks for you help. So calling exec(String[]) should work, instead of calling exec(String) twice?

Comment: No. You are not understanding. exec() creates a single process regardless of the number of arguments. The arguments are treated as a single command line with multiple arguments to the command. You need to accomplish what you want to do with one command. Find a single command line command that does what you want using adb shell.

For example exec("/system/bin/sh", "-c", "su && chmod 777" + file.getAbsolutePath()) will probably do what you want.

Comment: yes now I understood the problem, see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

---

Solved using this code to run the commands:

```
public static void runAsRoot(String[] cmds){
   try {
       Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
       DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
       for (String tmpCmd : cmds) {
           os.writeBytes(tmpCmd+"\n");
       }
       os.writeBytes("exit\nexit\n");
       os.flush();
       p.waitFor();
   } catch(IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch(InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```